# AVPlayer with AWS Cookie using AirPlay

Tags: swift, avplayer, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, airplay

I trying to play a HLS stream provided by CloudFront.

It works fine in the app. I just set the cookies in AVURLAsset then goes well.

The problem is happening when I select a device(Apple TV) in the list provided by AirPlay. The stream don't start.

I got the error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12926), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x28312ed90 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12926 "(null)"}}
```

I'm using this code to set the cookies:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://YOUR_VIDEO_URL.m3u8");
var cookies = [HTTPCookie]()
    if let cookie = json["cookie"] as? [String: String] {
    for key in cookie.keys {
        let cookieField = ["Set-Cookie": "\(key)=\(cookie[key] ?? "")"]
        let cookie = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: cookieField, for: url)
        cookies.append(contentsOf: cookie)
    }
}

// Assign cookies to AVPlayer
let values = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies)
let cookieOptions = ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": values]
let assets = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: cookieOptions)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: assets)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, you have to use AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and then make a request using AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest to be able to authenticate the chunk.

Comment: Were you able to stream it on Apple TV then? AVAssetResourceLoading didn't work for me.. Do you have a sample?

Comment: Josué Santos, can you please share sample code how to use AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and then make a request using AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest

Comment: Here is a sample.
https://gist.github.com/josuesasilva/e56ce6550f5cc00edf053b5a38e622a3

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate and then make a request
> using AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest to be able to authenticate the
> chunk.

[from OP's own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486044/avplayer-with-aws-cookie-using-airplay/69009671#comment107732075_57486044)

Answer (score -1):

Also the same issue happens when AirPlay device has no connection to the Internet.